# Blur when downscale image rendered by DirectX

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, fragment-shader

I am using DirectX for rendering video, but the issue is video is blur when downscale the video frame.
As I know, I need to write an high-quality down-scale filter in shader.hlsl file:

My current shader code:

```
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float3 inPos : POSITION;
    float2 inTexCoord : TEXCOORD;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 outPosition : SV_POSITION;
    float2 outTexCoord : TEXCOORD;
};

VS_OUTPUT vs_main(VS_INPUT input)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output;
    output.outPosition = float4(input.inPos, 1.0f);
    output.outTexCoord = input.inTexCoord;
    return output;
}

struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 inPosition : SV_POSITION;
    float2 inTexCoord : TEXCOORD;
};

Texture2D luminanceChannel : TEXTURE: register(t0);
Texture2D chrominanceChannel : TEXTURE: register(t1);
SamplerState defaultSampler : SAMPLER: register(s0);

static const float3x3 YUVtoRGBCoeffMatrix =
{
    1.164383f,  1.164383f, 1.164383f,
    0.000000f, -0.391762f, 2.017232f,
    1.596027f, -0.812968f, 0.000000f
};

float3 ConvertYUVtoRGB(float3 yuv)
{
    yuv -= float3(0.062745f, 0.501960f, 0.501960f);
    yuv = mul(yuv, YUVtoRGBCoeffMatrix);

    return saturate(yuv);
}

float4 PS(PS_INPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    float y = luminanceChannel.Sample(defaultSampler, input.inTexCoord);
    float2 uv = chrominanceChannel.Sample(defaultSampler, input.inTexCoord);
    return float4(ConvertYUVtoRGB(float3(y, uv)), 1.f);
}
```

Can you give me a guide for it? Thanks.

Comment: C# or C++? Why have you tagged both these very different languages? Please only tag the language you're actually program in.

Comment: sorry, I udapted it